# Skydrive as a version-control-system

Tags: version-control, onedrive

Is it possible to use Microsoft Skydrive as a source control system where I can check-in and check-out?

Comment: Isn't it just cloud storage? You could put your repo on it, but it's not an SCCS in itself AFAIK.

Comment: No, it does not have the capabilities of version control system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SkyDrive doesn't support check-in check-out.
You could use SkyDrive Pro against a SharePoint site (you can sign up for a free O365 [development license](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179924.aspx)) which would give you most of what you need but there wont be any Visual Studio integration.

But if all you want is the ability to store your source safely off-box then SkyDrive is fine but you'll need to put the compiled binaries somewhere else like [this](http://blog.kloud.com.au/2013/01/14/using-skydrive-for-source-code/)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to use it as a kind of source-control. But not direct skydrive, but with svn it's possible.

Just create the repository into the local mapped directory (which is automatically syncronized with the webspace). On a check-in the sources will be automatically uploaded to skydrive

Answer (score 0):

There's also the option of using Team Foundation Service: http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/tfs-welcome.aspx

It's a cloud-based TFS.  I used the demo and it was very nice.